# Git post-receive hook not firing external script

Tags: git, bash, hook

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I have a server that hosts websites and their git repositories.
2. I have a user named `git` that owns all the repos and has the ability to log in as any user without entering a password.
3. I created a hook called `post-receive` in the `hooks` directory on my repo.
4. I also created a script called `gitpull` that pulls the info to the sites automatically.

Everything is O.K. when I type this command:

```
su - git -c "/git/sitename.git/hooks/post-receive"
```

but when I push something from my development machine, it does not run the script `gitpull`.

Here are my files:

- `/etc/gitpull`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  su - $1 -c "cd ~/www;git pull;"
  ```
- `/git/sitename/hooks/post-receive`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  /etc/gitpull sitename
  ```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: {%GIT REPO%} is the name of the repo e.g. mysapmplerepo

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `su - sh -c ...`, since `git -c` is for setting one-off configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

The `post-receive` hook needs to be marked executable or git won't run it. When you test with `sh -c`, you're bypassing the execute permission check.

I bet it'll work if you run `chmod a+x /git/sitename.git/hooks/post-receive`.

---

So that's not it, huh?

Oh, `su` prompts for a password when you run it, doesn't it? You can't provide input to hooks, so you need to ensure that you can type `/git/sitename.git/hooks/post-receive` by itself as your normal user account and have it run without any interaction from you.